# kmeans complains "NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)", when there are none?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to run kmeans clustering analysis on a relatively simple data frame. However,

`kmeans(sample_data, centers = 4)`

doesn't work, as R states there are "NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)" (not true). Anyway, I tried

`kmeans(na.omit(sample_data), centers = 4)`

based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469671/error-in-do-onenmeth-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-1) (and other posts), and that didn't work. The only workaround I found was to exclude the non-numeric column (i.e., the observation names) using

`kmeans(sample_data[, 2:5], centers = 4)`

Unfortunately, this makes the clusters much less informative, since the points now have numbers instead of names. What's going on? Or how could I get the clustering with the right labels?

Edit: I'm trying to reproduce [this](https://uc-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering) procedure / result, but with a different data set. Notice that when the author [visualizes](https://uc-r.github.io/public/images/analytics/clustering/kmeans/unnamed-chunk-18-1.png) the clusters, the points are labelled according to the observations (the states, in that case; or "obs1, obs2, etc." in mine.)

Because of the workaround above (which drops the column with observation names), I get a sequence of numeric labels instead.

Code and dput below:

```
library(factoextra)
cluster <- kmeans(sample_data, centers = 4) #this doesn't work
cluster <- kmeans(sample_data[, 2:5], centers = 4) #this works
fviz_cluster(cluster, sample_data)
```

sample_data:

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 12L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), .Label = c("obs1", "obs10", "obs11", 
"obs12", "obs13", "obs14", "obs15", "obs16", "obs17", "obs18", 
"obs19", "obs2", "obs20", "obs21", "obs22", "obs23", "obs24", 
"obs25", "obs3", "obs4", "obs5", "obs6", "obs7", "obs8", "obs9"
), class = "factor"), variable1 = c(0, 0.383966783938484, 0.541654398529028, 
0.469060314591266, 0.397636449124337, 0.3944696359856, 0.368740430902284, 
0.998695171590958, 0.60013559365688, 0.543416096609665, 1, 0.287523586757021, 
0.57818096701751, 0.504722587360754, 0.284825226469556, 0.295250085072615, 
0.509782836343032, 0.392942062325636, 0.602608457169149, 0.474668174468815, 
0.219951650206242, 0.263837738487209, 0.530976492805559, 0.312401708505963, 
0.828799458392802), variable2 = c(0, 0.21094954480341, 0.374890541082605, 
0.502470003202637, 0.385212751959443, 0.499052863381439, 0.172887314327707, 
0.319869014605517, 0.484308813708282, 0.348608342250238, 0.474464311565186, 
0.380406312920036, 1, 0.618253544624658, 0.560290273167607, 0.676315913606924, 
0.339157532529115, 0.479005841710258, 0.576094917240369, 0.819742646967549, 
0.472559283375261, 0.45594685111211, 0.160720270709769, 0.494360626922513, 
0.658705091697224), variable3 = c(0, 0.0391726961740698, 0.157000498692027, 
0.194883594782107, 0.133290754949737, 0.199085094994071, 0.000551185924636259, 
0.418045152251051, 0.434858475480003, 0.443442199844268, 0.257231662911141, 
0.195570389942169, 0.46503468971732, 0.358104620337886, 0.391852363829371, 
0.39834809992812, 0.258870156344325, 0.38555892877453, 0.480559759927908, 
1, 0.15662554228071, 0.279363773961277, 0.11211821625736, 0.180885222092932, 
0.339650099009323), variable4 = c(0, 0.0464395032429444, 0.323768557597659, 
0.201813172242373, 0.302710768912681, 0.446027132614423, 0.542018940773003, 
1, 0.738123811706962, 0.550819613183929, 0.679555989322392, 0.563126171437818, 
0.470328070009844, 0.316069092919459, 0.344421820993065, 0.222931758003036, 
0.250406547916021, 0.381098780580988, 0.9526031202384, 0.174161621337361, 
0.260548409706516, 0.288399563112687, 0.617089845066814, 0.265314653254406, 
0.330637996311329)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

Comment: What do you mean, the right labels? You can use `sample_data$cluster <- kmeans(sample_data[-1], centers = 4)$cluster` to get the assigned clusters added to your data.frame?

Comment: Set the row names of the data frame to first column. `row.names(sample_data)<-sample_data[,1]`

Comment: @Axeman: Like this image: https://uc-r.github.io/public/images/analytics/clustering/kmeans/unnamed-chunk-18-1.png; details added to the question. Instead 'obs1, obs2, etc.,' labelling the points, I just get the numbers from 1-26. I can bind the cluster assignments back to the original data frame, but I'm not sure how to use fviz_cluster to visualize the distances / groupings using the updated data frame (it complains with a similar error about non-numeric data).

Comment: @Dave2e: I get `Error in .rowNamesDF<-(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to convert the column with the desired labels to row names with

`df <- tibble::column_to_rownames(df, var = "labels")`

That way the clustering algorithm won't even consider the labels, but will apply them to the points on the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

K-means *only* works on continuous variables.

It probably tried to convert your labels into numbers, and that did not work.

*Never* include identifier columns in analysis!

Proper data preprocessing is crucial and 90% of the work; you need to understand the requirements precisely. It is not sufficient to just make it run somehow - it is easy to make it run, but return useless results...

Comment: I appreciate the clarification, but in the article I linked above, the author runs the commands without removing the labels. More importantly, as shown in the image I linked, the author is able to visualize the clusters while displaying the labels. E.g.: https://uc-r.github.io/public/images/analytics/clustering/kmeans/unnamed-chunk-8-1.png. This is the question I'm trying to answer--how to visualize the clusters with their labels.

Comment: You can still have them set aside and use them later. But if you include them in the analysis, this makes your result statistically nonsense. That does not mean irrevocably destroying them.

Comment: My workaround set the labels aside, and what I'm trying to do now—the point of my question—is to use them again. Would you have any insight as to how I can accomplish this task?

Comment: You can set them as row names, for example. Or add them as another column. Or just leave them a separate list...

Comment: Would you know *how* I can do these things? I tried setting row names as per one of the comments, and that didn't work. If you know the mechanics of the answer, given the scope of the question, that would be amazing.

Comment: I don't use R much. Because it's syntax is brainfck, and no two libraries are compatible with each other... Just try a bit harder. I know it's possible.