# K-means clustering in R studio with 30+ microbiome samples

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, distance, k-means

I have 33 samples containing microbiome community data.

I have used the full_join command to combine all 33 samples into one dataframe. The dataframe looks like this:

```
          Samp1 Samp2 Samp3 Samp4
species1   0.1   8      0     2
species2   9     0.02   0     1
species3   0.3    1     1     0.1
species4    5     3    0.4    2
```

It is very large: 33 columns with 54,454 rows. I need to make a distance matrix to see how similar the columns (samples) are based on their abundance values (column values), which are based on species observations in each sample. From there (if I ever get there) I want to do k means clustering. Is this going to be possible in R? I have tried(with the corresponding error codes):

```
fviz_nbclust(samples, kmeans, method = "wss") + geom_vline(xintercept = 3, linetype = 2):
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In stats::dist(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

as well as:

```
mat <- dist(samples, method = "euclidean"):  
Error in do.call(".External", c(list(CFUN, x, y, pairwise, if (!is.function(method)) get(method) else method),  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed

dput(samples[1:20, 1:5]):
structure(list(species = c("A0A1I7T9A8_9PELO", "A0A7J7AV85_9COLE", 
"A0A653T3J9_9MICO", "A0A6B0USQ1_IXORI", "W1W9S2_9STAP", "A0A653THV2_9MICO", 
"A0A0J7YLY8_BETVV", "A0A077ZKY0_TRITR", "A7A2I7_BIFAD", "A0A2C8AE20_9ACTN", 
"V8M0T5_STRTR", "A0A1B2YXC3_9BACT", "A0A2L2YUX1_PARTP", "A0A0K9Q7A6_SPIOL", 
"A0A0W0XZ17_9GAMM", "I0S7Z1_STRAP", "A0A1I7SXW9_9PELO", "A0A6A5L026_LUPAL", 
"A0A2Z5TND2_9STRE", "T1DQS5_ANOAQ"), mvh1 = c(27.76699, 9.61795, 
5.04776, 2.81076, 2.73102, 2.34273, 2.21013, 1.46822, 1.22727, 
1.13887, 0.90139, 0.83551, 0.82425, 0.74018, 0.67257, 0.6093, 
0.57897, 0.51136, 0.5001, 0.49229), mvh2 = c(NA, 0.00531, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), mvh3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.96, 2.88, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.92, NA, NA, NA, NA), mvh4 = c(0.02, 0.02285, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.01286, 2.4369, NA, 0.23426, 5.17091, 0.04857, 
0.02571, NA, NA, 0.05142, 0.00571, 0.27283, 1.43414, 0.09428)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also when trying dist() on samptest, a subset of the same dataset, I do not get a matrix but I just get this:

```
 1            2            3            4            5            6
                7            8            9           10           11           12
               13           14           15           16           17           18
               19           20           21           22           23           24
               25           26           27           28           29           30
               31           32           33           34           35           36
               37           38           39           40           41           42
               43           44           45           46           47           48
               49           50           51           52           53           54
               55           56           57           58           59           60
               61           62           63           64           65           66
               67           68           69           70           71           72
               73           74           75           76           77           78
               79           80           81           82           83           84
               85           86           87           88           89           90
               91           92           93           94           95           96
               97           98           99          100          101          102
              103          104          105          106          107          108
              109          110          111          112          113          114
              115          116          117          118          119          120
```

So it doesn't seem it be calculating relationships between the columns.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of `dput(samptest[1:20, 1:5])`? And which is your data set with 33 columns and 54k rows, `samples` or `samptest`?

Comment: Sorry, samptest was a smaller subset I was testing out. The large dataset with 54k rows is samples. I added the output of dput.

Comment: The first column is not numeric, try `dist(samples[-1], method = "euclidean")` to remove it from the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, I got the same error code: Error in do.call(".Call", c(list(method), list(x), list(y), pairwise,  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed

Comment: See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469671/error-in-do-onenmeth-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-1), your data has lots of `NA`'s.